# Setting the color of the TabItem header's foreground when the tab is clicked and not clicked

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, controltemplate, tabitem

I have this `TabControl` in my application:

```
<TabControl Width="100" Height="100">
    <TabControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" x:Key="TabItemStyle">
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                        <Border x:Name="Chrome"
                                BorderBrush="Blue" 
                                Background="Transparent">
                            <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header"
                                              Margin="0,0,0,3"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="Chrome" Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,3"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="Chrome" Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TabControl.Resources>

    <TabItem Style="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle}">
        <TabItem.Header>
             <Label Content="Tab 1" />
        </TabItem.Header>
    </TabItem>

    <TabItem Style="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle}">
        <TabItem.Header>
             <Label Content="Tab 2" />
        </TabItem.Header>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

When I click a tab in the `TabControl`, a blue line is displayed below the tab header.
 This is beside the point, but I'm sure the style I have will be useful.

In the tab headers there are labels.
I would like to change the foreground of labels according to:

- When the tab is clicked, the label's foreground should be `Red`.
- When the tab is not clicked, the label's foreground should be `Gray`.

I assume I can use the trigger I already have in the `ControlTemplate` to determine when the tab was clicked or not.

But I don't know what I need to do to set the labels foreground accordingly in the style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a [`DataTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatemplate?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.DataTemplate);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-5.0) as [`HeaderTemplate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.headeredcontentcontrol.headertemplate?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Controls.HeaderedContentControl.HeaderTemplate);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-5.0) and use a [`DataTrigger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.datatrigger?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.DataTrigger);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-5.0) that sets the `Foreground` color of the `Label`s depending on the selection state of the containing `TabItem`s, which is bound using a [`RelativeSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Data.Binding.RelativeSource);k(VS.XamlEditor)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-5.0). The separate header template also reduces the redundancy in your `TabItem`s, because you do not have to define the `Label` in each time again.

```
<TabControl Width="100"
            Height="100">
   <TabControl.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}"
             x:Key="TabItemStyle">
         <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
                 Value="Stretch" />
         <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
                 Value="Stretch" />
         <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
               <DataTemplate>
                  <Label x:Name="TabItemHeaderLabel" Foreground="Gray" Content="{Binding}" />
                  <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="TabItemHeaderLabel" Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                     </DataTrigger>
                  </DataTemplate.Triggers>
               </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
         <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                  <Border x:Name="Chrome"
                          BorderBrush="Blue"
                          Background="Transparent">
                     <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header"
                                       Margin="0,0,0,3"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                       VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                  </Border>
                  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                     <Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelected"
                              Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Chrome"
                                Property="BorderThickness"
                                Value="0,0,0,3" />
                     </Trigger>
                     <Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelected"
                              Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="Chrome"
                                Property="BorderThickness"
                                Value="0,0,0,0" />
                     </Trigger>
                  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
               </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
      </Style>
   </TabControl.Resources>

   <TabItem Style="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle}"
            Header="Tab 1"/>

   <TabItem Style="{DynamicResource TabItemStyle}"
            Header="Tab 2"/>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: Thank you!

There is still a bug.
The Red color is just displayed for a short time. It then falls back to the Gray color. Even if the Tab is selected.
I cannot reproduce this behavior in the sample code, only in my real application.
Any suggestions what could be the problem?

Comment: @Mc_Topaz Since you can only reproduce the behavior in your real application, there might be some code that changes or resets the selection, e.g. the `SelectedItem` property, but that is only an assumption.